# code igniter error: Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings. Filename: core/Loader.php Line Number: 346

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm developing a website application using codeigniter at localhost and then i host it in hawkhost.

At localhost it runs well, but at host there's and error :

> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>   Filename: core/Loader.php Line Number: 346

this is my db configuration

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = '****';
$db['default']['password'] = '****';
$db['default']['database'] = '****';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I know many people already asked this problem but it doesn't seems to solve anything on my case.
changing `$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;` to false only hide the error but when i tried to get data from query it doesn't return anything.

I also tried to change `$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;` to true and still doesn't work.

Any help please?

Comment: check the credentials and i think credentials should be confidential..

Comment: @sgt what do you mean by credential? how can i modified that?

Comment: db name, password, username etc...

Comment: i'm sure they're correct. i don't find answer anywhere about how to fix this

Comment: Have you done this? https://support.hawkhost.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/48/12/how-do-i-create-a-mysql-database

Comment: Don't slough off @sgt's comment; this is almost surely due to your credentials. Are you sure the host is 'localhost'? Log into your web server via the terminal and try `mysql -u<username> -p <dbname>` and then type your password when it asks. Then run a query; something your app does, `select * from users limit 1` or something. Did you get a result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is really due to credentials.
I test it using simple code to check if connection can be made.

The problem is in username, i realize there's additional suffix when using hosting. such as `suffix_user`
I think the same errors in Core/Loader.php Line Number: 346 has the same solution. make sure the username, password and host are right.

It's solved. Thank you everyone for helping.

Comment: @JCm in this case suffix_user is myUsername_DbUser. example : stormrage_admin2.

Comment: how will I check if theres an additional suffic when hosting?

Comment: The suffix can be seen in cPanel. It's neccessary if it's shared hosting and the suffix is also applicable for db name.

Answer (score 6):

Just change `localhost` to the local ipaddress i.e. `127.0.0.1` and it will start working.

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
```

to

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it saved my day

Comment: that is not a general solution

Answer (score 5):

In my case setting pconnect to false worked.

```
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time this problem happens when codeigniter is in live environment.

That’s why I assumed a domain name ‘(example: domainname.com)’ and after creating a mysql database (example: testDb) and user name (example: testUser) you will find a prefix name automatically added with your mysql database name and user name like ‘domainname_ testDb’ and ‘domainname_ testUser’.

Now in codeigniter /application/config/database.php edit following:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'domainname_ testDb ';
$db['default']['password'] = '*******';
$db['default']['database'] = 'domainname_ testUser';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre']= '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: For me its `$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;` issue, so i changed to `FALSE`, now works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Just change

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
```

to

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

and voila.

Answer (score 0):

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'domainname_ testDb ';
$db['default']['password'] = '*******';
$db['default']['database'] = 'domainname_ testUser';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre']= '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Hi, do add a bit of explanation along with the code as it helps to understand your code. Code only answers are frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is having this issue, try disabling SE-Linux if you have it enabled. It was causing the connection issues for me, with php 5.4.

Also worth checking is switching

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

to

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

as mysql is depreciated after php 5.5.